# Access to chain extension method from another module in ink!

Tags: ink, chain-extension

## Summary

I am using an Ink! smart contract (implemented in contract.rs) code calling a chain extension method.

This works well.

However, I want to split my code and call the extension method in a new module (let's call it util.rs).

What is the idiomatic way to share the same env with this module.
In other words I want to be able to call self.env().extension.my_method from utils.rs method.

## Update

I will ask my question in a more concise and concrete way, suppose the following code in a ink! smart contract:

```rust
use crate::CustomEnvironment;

// use ink_env::chain_extension::ChainExtension; NOT EXPOSED PUBLICLY

// Suppose we want to define this method that takes the extension as parameter
fn call_a_method_extension(ext: <<CustomEnvironment>::ChainExtension as ChainExtensionInstance>::Instance) {
    // use ext here
    // ext.call_on_chain_method
}
// ...
let ext = Self::env().extension();
// Info from rust-analyser:
// ChainExtensionInstance<Self = Environment<Self = E>::ChainExtension>::Instance
// <<E as Environment>::ChainExtension as ChainExtensionInstance>::Instance

// we want to pass ext to call_a_method_extension
call_a_method_extension(ext);

// ...
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(scale_info::TypeInfo))]
pub enum CustomEnvironment {}

impl Environment for CustomEnvironment {
    const MAX_EVENT_TOPICS: usize = <ink_env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::MAX_EVENT_TOPICS;

    type AccountId = <ink_env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::AccountId;
    type Balance = <ink_env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::Balance;
    type Hash = <ink_env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::Hash;
    type BlockNumber = <ink_env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::BlockNumber;
    type Timestamp = <ink_env::DefaultEnvironment as Environment>::Timestamp;

    type ChainExtension = ConcreteOps;
}
```

What type need to be written to the ext parameter in call_a_method_extension method ?

## Archive

### First attempt

I try to overlad the + operation with a basic functions for now.

### Share the EnvAccess to a struct defined in util.rs

```rust
// utils.rs
use crate::CustomEnvironment;
use ink_lang::EnvAccess;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct VeryUtil<'a> {
    pub value: ink_prelude::vec::Vec<u8>,
    pub extension: EnvAccess<'a, CustomEnvironment>,
}

impl<'a> VeryUtil<'a> {
    pub fn new(
        value: ink_prelude::vec::Vec<u8>,
        extension: EnvAccess<'a, CustomEnvironment>,
    ) -> Self {
        VeryUtil { value, extension }
    }
}

impl core::ops::Add<VeryUtil<'_>> for VeryUtil<'_> {
    // For the next line I get
    // generic associated types are unstable
    // type Output<'a> = VeryUtil<'a>;

    // for now I tested with
    type Output = Vec<u8>;

    fn add(self, rhs: VeryUtil) -> Vec<u8> {
        println!("> add is called");

        let val = self
            .extension
            .extension()
            .add_values(&self.value, &rhs.value);

        val.unwrap()
    }
}
```

Here I get a warning when the output was the same struct, I commented in the code.
A subsidiary question is how to avoid to share for each struct the env, but without it I would not be able to call the extension method in the Add overload part!

### Use the defined  struct in one of the exposed contract methods:

```rust
// contract.rs
1 let very_util_val1 = crate::util::VeryUtil::new(my_vec1.clone(), self.env());
2 let very_util_val2 = crate::util::VeryUtil::new(my_vec2.clone(), self.env());
3 // All the code purpose is to be able to do this!!!
4 let result = very_util_val1 + very_util_val2
```

I get the following error for line 1 and 2 :

```
cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
```

My initial choice was to share a *__ink_ConreteOpsInstance* (self.env().extension) but I did not know how to define this type in my struct.

### Another idea

Maybe I can ask access like the contract module with the following macro ...

```rust
#[ink::contract(env = crate::CustomEnvironment)]
```

... but this module is not a contract just a sub module.

Comment: Can you provide a small repo reproducer, so I can play around and see what works?

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to reference the chain extension method from a different file.

It's good that you raised this and I just created this issue for it: https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1719.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked how the module separation is done for the [Swanky-node](https://github.com/AstarNetwork/swanky-node/blob/main/runtime/src/lib.rs)?

Comment: I will check it, thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).